# Errors reading PDF with CAM-PDF: use of uninitialized value in addition <+> line 667

Tags: perl, pdf, cpan, strawberry-perl, cam-pdf

I'm new to perl and I'm trying to read a pdf file using `CAM::PDF` here is my code:

When I try to run this in the command prompt I get these errors:

> "Use of uninitialized value in addition <+> at
>   C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/CAM/PDF.pm line 667 ...  substr outside of
>   str at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/CAM/PDF.pm line 657 ... (at the
>   end)... "Bad request for object 60 at position 0 in the file Can't
>   call method "getPageContentTree" on the undefined value at C:...

The weird thing is I have the exact same files and program on a separate computer that runs just fine. It prints everything perfectly where this computer can't.

I've tried reinstalling CAM::PDF and reinstalling `cpan`. The reinstall actually failed for some reason too. Thanks for the help.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CAM::PDF;
use CAM::PDF::PageText;

#in cmd: courts.pl samplePDF.pdf

my $filename = shift || die "Supply pdf on command line\n";

my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new($filename);


#print text_from_page(1);

my $string = text_from_page(1);
#print $string;

$string =~ s/\b \b//g;
print $string;

open(my $fh, '>', 'reports.txt');
print $fh "$string";
close $fh;
print "done\n";

sub text_from_page {
my $pg_num = shift;

return
CAM::PDF::PageText->render($pdf->getPageContentTree($pg_num));
}
```